# Jquery mouseout stop playing?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, hover, playback

Good Evening everyone,
im somehow stuck on a simple Problem, but just can't figuere out how to solve it. Im playing around the first time with jquery.

Now on mousenter it plays the audiofile just fine, but i tried to implement a on mouseout function to stop the audio file from playing.
I simple can't get it to work.

I hope someone can help me out that would be great :)

```
<div class="buttonmit2ani">

            <audio id="beep-one"  preload="auto">
                <source src="audio/baby.mp3"></source>
                <source src="audio/beep.ogg"></source>
                Your browser isn't invited for super fun time.
            </audio> 
            <script>
              var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
              $(".buttonmit2ani")
                .mouseenter(function() {
                  beepOne.play();
              );
            </script>               

</div>
```

Comment: Where is your "mouseout" handler?  Shouldn't you tack that on right after the `.mouseenter` handler? See: [.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) It should call the theoretical `.stop()` function.  Is that not working? Also, where is your closing `}` brace after `beepOne.play();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];

$('.buttonmit2ani').mouseover(function(){
    beepOne.play();
}).mouseout(function(){
    beepOne.stop(); // need to write this method or .pause()
});
```

Comment: Nice, only thing is that I don't think there is a `.stop()` function for `<audio>` tags.  Try `.pause()`.

Comment: Yeah, that was just an abstract method that you need to write. Thanks. (I updated the code) :)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `.stop()` function (at least not in Chrome).  Use `.pause()`

```js
var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
$(".buttonmit2ani").mouseenter(function() {
  beepOne.play();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  beepOne.pause();
});
```

```css
.buttonmit2ani {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #E9EAEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttonmit2ani">
  <audio id="beep-one" preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/acdc.ogg">
      Your browser is not invited for super fun time.
  </audio>
</div>
```